# How can I make it so my discord bot mentions a specific person when they type?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm putting this in a Cog. I want to make it so that if the author is a specific person and they type anything, the bot will mention them and reply.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

class jtieu(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Bot 3 is ready.")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def jtieu2(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author == "CxS#3441" :
            await ctx.channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} ok")



def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(jtieu(client))
```

I'm not too sure if I'm supposed to use ctx.author.mention in this context, and I'm fairly new to how Cogs work in discord.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a mention specifically for one user it might be a better idea to copy the user's id and use it instead of a nickname as it will work even when they change their name.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author.id == 1234567890: # example id
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} ok")
```

***Remember that it requires [`intents.messages`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Intents.messages).***

[Simple Cogs Example](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cogs#quick-example)

Comment: I thought it would be using something like events, no? Like if I wanted to do that in the main file rather than a Cog, wouldn't I be using something like `client.event` rather than `client.commands()`? And I'm not trying to make it a command, I just want the bot to respond whenever a specific person types.

Comment: I just edited my answer. I thought you wanted to create a command because of `ctx` in your code. My bad. It should work now.

Comment: Ah I see, it was because of the function that it didn't work. Is it required to use on_message when doing something like this? I can't use another function name?

Comment: You can use any name you want in commands, but if you are trying to do something when a message is sent or other condition happens you want to use [events](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference).

Comment: Also, if it worked please accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Gotcha, sorry, I'm still new to this site. Thank you very much!